# Weird Javascript does not work when moved to webserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I`ve encountered a weird problem today. I worke in a project loally, stright from windows folder to Notepad++ - Whan I open in a browser works perfecly. However, when I send to a webserver, it does not work.

It shows the loader, but no action.

You can see the version on the web at:
www.neevasoft.com/cleiarte    or
www.masterinforj.com.br/cleiarte

I was thinking of a problem between modernzr and iframe. But not really sure if there is incompatibilities.

Anyone anythoughts?

```
   <!doctype html>
        <html class="no-js" lang="en">
        <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Clei Arte</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/retina.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animated.min.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">  

    </head>     
    <body>
    <div class="loader"><div class="bar"><strong>CLEI ARTE</strong><span class="progress color-2"><span>abrindo...</span></span></div></div>
    <header class="alt color-2" data-animation="fadeIn fast" data-delay="0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 for-mobile-header-1">
                    <h1><a href="#pagetop"><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 for-mobile-header-2 for-one-page">
                    <div class="mobile-wrapper clearfix">
                        <nav class="main-menu clearfix navbar navbar-default">
                            <div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-main-menu">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">                                    
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">navegação</a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse m-menu" id="top-main-menu">
                            <ul class="sf-menu superfish-li-relative color-2">
                                <li class="current-menu-item">
                                    <a href="#welcome">Principal</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#services">Quem Somos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">Cleidson</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#blog">Video Book</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contacts">contato</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--Welcome section-->
    <section class="waypoint video-block fullscreen" data-hash="welcome">
        <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="video/forest.jpg" class="background-video">
            <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/forest.ogm" type="video/ogm">
        </source></source></video>
        <div class="text-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix">
                        <h6><a href="#services" class="to-text" data-animation="flipInX" data-delay="0">A Agência</a></h6>
                        <span class="learn-more" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.6">-  Que você precisa  -</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay color-2" style="opacity:0.5;"></div>
    </section>
    <!--Services section-->
    <section class="alt-bg-1 color-2 waypoint" data-hash="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="spacer" style="height:82px;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="tAc">
                        <h2 class="big-title white color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0">Quem somos</h2>
                        <p style="max-width:500px; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:63px;" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0.2">Somos uma empresa de produção, casting e eventos. Produzimos Vídeo book e fotos para atores, modelos, Figurantes e promotores. Contamos com um casting expansivo e um público diversificado para vários seguimentos. .</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 top-features color-2 content-element">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe feature" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.3"></i>
                    <h3 data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5" class="white">Missão</h3>
                    <p data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.7">Produzir um trabalho de qualidade com muita competência e credibilidade mantendo um casting de profissionais qualificados atendendo a demanda dos nossos clientes. Expandir a cultura e informação acrescentando talentos no mercado Audiovisual. .</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 top-features color-2 content-element">
                    <i class="fa fa-film feature" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.3"></i>
                    <h3 data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5" class="white">Mercado de atuação:</h3>
                    <p data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.7">
                    <li>Produção de Material Profissional para atores: Vídeo book e fotos. </li>
                    <li>Produção de Plateias programas de TV.</li>
                    <li>Produção de Linhas de Frente para Platéias de programas de TV. </li></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 top-features color-2 content-element">
                    <i class="fa fa-road feature" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.3"></i>
                    <h3 data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5" class="white">Mercado de atuação:</h3>
                    <p data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.7">
                    <li>Figuração para Series, Filmes, Comercias e Novelas.</li>
                    <li>Produção de elenco para Filmes, seriados e novelas.</li>
                    <li>Supervisão e promoção de eventos em Shoppings e Feiras.</li> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer" style="height:41px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Video block-->
        <div class="video-block features-watch alt-bg" style="padding-top:189px; padding-bottom:173px;">
            <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="video/horses.jpg" class="background-video">
                <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/horses.ogm" type="video/ogm">
            </source></source></video>
            <div class="parallax-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                            <iframe width="800" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pj435r22UBE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay color-2" style="opacity:0.5;"></div>
        </div>
    </section>      
    <!--About section-->
    <section class="alt-bg-1 color-2 waypoint" data-hash="about">
        <div class="spacer" style="height:76px;"></div>
        <div class="alt-bg-3 color-2" id="team">
            <div class="container" id="meet_team">
                <div class="spacer" style="height:77px;"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tAc">
                        <h2 class="big-title white color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0">Sobre o produtor e Proprietário da Empresa:</h2>
                        <div class="spacer" style="height:6px;"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-container" data-animation="flipInY slow" data-delay="0.4">
                                <div class="flipper">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                        <span class="author-flip color-2">
                                            <a class="white" href="#"></a>
                                            <span class="post"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-container" data-animation="flipInY slow" data-delay="0.4">
                                <div class="flipper">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <img src="img/clei.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                        <span class="author-flip color-2">
                                            <a class="white" href="#">Cleidson Gonçalves</a>
                                            <span class="post"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back color-2"><div class="wrapper-tb"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="for-mobile-flip">
                                                    <h4>Cleidson Gonçalves</h4>
                                                    <span class="post color-2"></span>
                                                    <p class="flip-text">
                                                        Formado em Produção de Radio e TV Pela universidade Estácio de Sá em Dezembro de 2009,
                                                        Cleidson Gonçalves segue sua carreira como autor roteirista, diretor e produtor Audiovisual.
                                                        Autor do livro – Sem medo sem máscara publicado em 2015- Cleidson Já trabalhou como auxiliar de 
                                                        figurino na empresa Rede Globo em 2011 e 2012, atuou produziu e escreveu algumas peças de comedias
                                                        no Rio de janeiro e atualmente trabalha como produtor de plateias nos programas de humor do Canal
                                                        Multishow. Dentre eles: Vai que cola – 2014 / 2015 – Premio Multishow de humor – 2013/ 2014/ 2015 
                                                        Prêmio Multishow de música 2013 e 2014. Programa Samantha – Não ta fácil para ninguém 2014.  Trair
                                                        e coçar é só começar estrelado por Cacau Protazio – 2014 / 2015 e Ferdinando Show 2015 e 2016.

                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-container" data-animation="flipInY slow" data-delay="0.4">
                                <div class="flipper">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                        <span class="author-flip color-2 color-2">
                                            <a class="white" href="#"></a>
                                            <span class="post"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer" style="height:56px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="spacer" style="height:59px;"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Clients section-->
    <section class="waypoint parallax-section" data-hash="clients">
        <div class="parallax-holder">
            <div class="paralayer" style="background-image: url(img/forest/forest-middle-parallax-bg.jpg);" data-paraspeed="0.5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay color-2"></div>
    </section>
    <!--Portfolio section-->
    <section class="waypoint" data-hash="portfolio">
        <div class="alt-bg-1 color-2">
            <div class="spacer" style="height:94px;"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="tAc">
                            <h2 class="big-title white color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0">Nossa Galeria</h2>
                            <p style="max-width:500px; margin:0 auto;" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0.2">Alguns dos nossos trabalhos.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer" style="height:79px;"></div>
        </div>  
        <div id="ajaxed_content"></div>
        <div class="portfolio color-2">
            <div class="additional-area color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.3">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="filters filters-center color-2 clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <div class="full isotope-bg">
                    <div class="clearfix portfolioContainer" data-animation="fadeIn" data-delay="0">

                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Evento">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Forest and sheep" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image"  href="img/cleiarte1.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Evento</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Super</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Producao">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Forest road" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte2.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Produção</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Equipe</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Casting">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Sunny meadow" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte3.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Casting</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Aprovados</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Evento">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="High mountain" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte1.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Evento</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Super</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Producao">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Forest and sheep" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image"  href="img/cleiarte2.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Produção</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Equipe</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Casting">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Forest road" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte3.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Casting</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Aprovados</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Evento">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="Sunny meadow" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte1.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Evento</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Super</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="portfolios_listing full  alt-animation" data-category="Producao">
                            <div class="entry-image"><a class="thumb" data-title="High mountain" data-lightbox="gallery-main-image" href="img/cleiarte2.jpg">
                                    <div class="overlay-alt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cell-2">
                                                <div class="top-title-gallery animated-pf "><h2 class="color-2">Produção</h2></div>
                                                <div class="entry-content animated-pf ">Equipe</div>
                                            </div></div></div>
                                    <img src="img/cleiarte2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                </a></div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Compose layouts parallax block-->
    <!--Blog section-->
    <section class="alt-bg-1 color-2 waypoint" data-hash="blog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="spacer" style="height:96px;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="tAc">
                        <h2 class="big-title white color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0">Videobook - Cleiarte<br />
                        <h3 class="white">“Seu vídeo como uma cena de novela”</h3></h2>
                    </div><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.2">
                    <div class="inner-decor">

                        <h3 class="white">A Agência</h3>
                        <p>Focamos na naturalidade, aprimoramos o talento, explorando o que há de melhor no ator para que a cena fique perfeita.
                        Gravamos no lugar ideal. Locações que valorizam a cena e o ator. Direção e iluminação minuciosa fazem de Videobook- Cleiarte,
                        um trabalho de qualidade com muita credibilidade, saindo na frente, pois quebramos a idéia de que vídeo book e fotos têm que 
                        ser feito em estudo com fundo branco e o ator automático falando o texto olhando para a câmera. Com pesquisa profunda descobrimos 
                        que produtores de elenco e diretores do meio, gostam de assistir vídeos naturais com cenas reais onde o ator, passe naturalidade,
                        o que é fundamental para televisão com a fotografia não ia ser diferente. Nossas fotos são bem naturais e diferentes valorizando o
                        ator e modelo.  </p><br /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5">
                    <div class="inner-decor">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pj435r22UBE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div><br />
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.2">
                    <div class="inner-decor">

                        <h3 class="white">Oferecemos para o cliente:</h3>
                        <p> <li>Vídeo book de cena.</li>
                            <li>Vídeo book monólogo.</li>
                            <li>Book fotográfico de externa. </li>
                            <li>Direção e preparação para o ator antes da gravação.</li>
                            <li>Maquiagem e cabelo feito pela nossa empresa.</li>
                            <li>Link do vídeo book no You Tube e no site da empresa.</li>
                            <li>Vídeo gravado com Câmera HD Digital </li>
                            <li>Edição profissional. </li>
                            <li>Cenas com locações de externas, valorizando o ator e os textos.</li>
                            <li>Textos exclusivos e registrados escritos pelo produtor e Roteirista – Cleidson Gonçalves. </li>
                            <li>Entregamos um DVD Original para o cliente contendo a cena e o monologo. Capa com foto, nome, DRT e contatos do ator. </li>
                            <li>Vai junto também o CD com as fotos do book de externa. </li></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5">
                    <div class="inner-decor">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pj435r22UBE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div><br />
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.2">
                    <div class="inner-decor">

                        <h3 class="white">Como trabalhamos</h3>
                        <p>
                        Pelo telefone ou e-mail marcamos a data do primeiro encontro. Uma reunião onde vamos marcar um dia para o ensaio e um para a gravação. Nesse primeiro encontro, Mandamos para o e-mail do ator algumas opções de textos exclusivos um monólogo e uma cena para o ator escolher e decorar. <br /><br />

                        No dia do ensaio vamos dar dicas e preparar totalmente o ator para a cena, com exercícios de corpo, técnica vocal e comportamento na frente das câmeras. Nesse dia o ator já deve estar com os dois textos decorados cena e monólogo, vamos trabalhar as marcações e finalizar a cena.<br /><br />

                        No terceiro encontro gravamos o vídeo.<br /><br />

                        Damos o prazo de 15 dias para a entrega de todo material editado e finalizado.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.5">
                    <div class="inner-decor">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pj435r22UBE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-12 small-blog color-2" data-animation="fadeInUp " data-delay="0.2">
                    <div class="inner-decor">

                        <h3 class="white">Preços:</h3>
                        <p>
                        <li><strong>Cena:</strong> R$ 600,00. </li>
                        <li><strong>Monologo:</strong> R$ 500,00.</li>
                        <li><strong>Book fotográfico de externa 30 fotos 3 produções:</strong> R$ 300,00</li><br />
                        <strong>Total:</strong> R$ 1.400,00<br /><br />
                        <strong>PROMOÇÃO PACOTE TOP: 
                        Pacote Top: Monologo + cena + 30 Fotos = R$ 1000,000. <br />
                        OBS: Só o pacote top inclui o link do vídeo no youtube e no site da empresa. </strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer" style="height:119px;"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Contacts section-->
    <section data-hash="contacts" class="waypoint alt-bg-1 color-2">
        <div id="mapheader" class="google-map " data-address="Av. Olegário Maciel, 460 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil" data-animation="fadeIn" data-delay="0"></div>
        <div class="alt-bg-1 color-2">
            <div class="spacer" style="height:81px;"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="tAc">
                            <h2 class="big white" style="max-width:710px; display:inline-block;" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0">Venha fazer parte do nosso casting e ser agenciado pela cleiarte.<br /><h3 class="white">Horario de atendimento- das 10 as 17 horas. </h3></h2><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="cleiarte1@gmail.com">
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="E-mail do site">
                            <span class="contact-column-1" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0.2">Av. Olegário Maciel, 460 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro</span>
                            <span class="contact-column-2" data-animation="fadeInUp slow" data-delay="0.4">Cel:(021) 3442-1470  Cel:(021) 99744-7927  </span><br />

                            <form method="post" id="contact_form" role="form" name="contact_form" class="big clearfix alt alt white-form" action="" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.6">     
                                <div class="contact-onehalf fLeft"><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="name"></div>
                                <div class="contact-onehalf fRight"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="email"></div>
                                <div class="clear-2"><input type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" class="name"></div>
                                <div><textarea name="message" placeholder="Comment"></textarea></div>
                                <div class="spacer" style="height:12px;"></div>
                                <div class="buttons clearfix">
                                    <button type="submit" class="button8 btn-1 send color-2">Enviar</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer" style="height:78px;"></div>
        </div>
    </section>  
    <!--Footer section-->
    <section id="footer" class="color-2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="widget socials tAc double-indent">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/cleiarte" class="social_links color-2 facebook"><span>facebook</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="tAc">
                            Copyright &copy; 2016 Cleiarte - Todos os direitos reservados - Desenvolvido por <a href="http://www.masterinforj.com.br">Wizen</a>.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/modernizr.min.js'></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/script.js'></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have about 51 console errors, I would start with that

Comment: How does the folder structure look like?

Comment: Index.html at root than folders CSS - fonts - img - js - video

Comment: I'll check the console Chris. Didn't do that yet.

Comment: All I can suggest is make sure you uploaded all your files, because it looks like the page can't find the resources it is trying to access.

Comment: Thank you Chris! It1s working now!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have uploaded every file and folders that are linked to that page  to the server.